# How to handle input value in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, types, union-types

I want to add Typescript to an existing project.
The problem is that the type to be used as an input value is ambiguous.
Because in an existing project, I only used a string value as an input value.
For example, when I enter an price, I used to initialize it with an empty string value("") to see the placeholder at first.
Only numeric string can be entered via validation function and added comma to value when blur event is fired.

However, when I send it to the backend, I changed it to a number so all the data I get from the backend is a numeric type.
I'm trying to define data and types on the redux, but is it right to just declare it as a union type?
Or is there a better way?

This is the item type that I defined.
I want to use quantity and price as input value, but it's type is number so, I got a type error.

```
export interface Item {
    id: number
    category: string
    quantity: number
    price: number;
}
```

Comment: You can typecast the numbers you get back? `0.toString()` is `"0"`.

Comment: @J.Hesters `0.toString()` is a syntax error, `(0).toString()` (or `0 .toString()`!) is `'0'`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but it seems like you need different types for different situations. You need a type to use with the UI (string), since input values are strings, but you need a different type for use elsewhere (number in your example). I'd keep them separate, but convert to number very early.

Comment: In state/logic/etc. you would maintain the exact types you need/expect for your data.  Converting from something like an input string to a number type would be isolated to the UI which accepts that input.